# should I call `executorService.shutdown` and `executorService.awaitTermination`?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, executorservice

```
/**
 * Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
 * request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is
 * interrupted, whichever happens first.
 *
 * @param timeout the maximum time to wait
 * @param unit the time unit of the timeout argument
 * @return {@code true} if this executor terminated and
 *         {@code false} if the timeout elapsed before termination
 * @throws InterruptedException if interrupted while waiting
 */
boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException;
```

What does this `completed execution after a shutdown` mean?

Does it mean I have to execute a `shutdown` API ?

Should my code be like:

```
@Test
public void setUserNamePropertyFromMultiThreadsUpdatesCorrectly() throws Exception {
        ..

        List<Callable<Void>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            callables.add(new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    ..
                    assertTrue(isSuccess);
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        try {
            executorService.invokeAll(callables);
            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

   ..
}
```

or

```
 try {
                executorService.invokeAll(callables);
                executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

What does `This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to
     complete execution` mean? sending stop interrupt even if the task is not completed?

```
/**
 * Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted
 * tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.
 * Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
 *
 * <p>This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to
 * complete execution.  Use {@link #awaitTermination awaitTermination}
 * to do that.
 */
void shutdown();
```

Comment: Instead of  `callables.add(new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {`..., it is much more readable to use the Lambda syntax `callables.add(() -> { ...; return null; })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutdown` : no more incoming tasks.

`awaitTermination` : invoked after a shutdown request.

> What does this completed execution after a shutdown mean?

You should call `shutdown` first. Otherwise, you might be waiting for a very long time, since `awaitTermination` doesn't actually shut down your executor.

> Does it mean I have to execute a shutdown API?

Yes, As explained above

> What does This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to
>        complete execution mean?

It means, `shutdown` is not a blocking call... method returns immediately after invocation. To be blocked till everything is complete.. you call `awaitTermination`.

Comment: can tasks continue running after `shut down` ? because I want the tasks to execute until completion or timeout

`This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to
     complete execution`

Comment: Yes... the tasks already submitted will execute but no more tasks will be accepted

Comment: how do you see this in the documentation? I see `This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to  complete execution`

Comment: It means... it is not a blocking call... method returns immediately after invocation. To be blocked till eveything is complete.. you call awaitTermination., updated the answer for that

Comment: so if it isn't a blocking call - how do i know the executor doesn't stop submitted tasks? from the doc?

Comment: Yes.. doc clearly specifies that. Otherwise, you can check any implementation of executor service to further verify it.